# How to get a method list in Eclipse without inherited ones (shortcut)?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-completion

Everyone knows the Ctrl+Space shortcut in Eclipse but I got one question on that.
If you use this shortcut, you'll get a list of visible methods and fields. e.g.:

```
JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
table.<Ctrg+Space>
```

.. and you'll get a list of JTable methods, JComponent ones etc. So inherited methods are listed as well. Sometimes this list is very long...

My question is: Does Eclipse offer an option to hide the inherited methods? So I just get a list of methods of this specific class? E.g. when I use..

```
table.<Ctrg+Space>
```

..I'll get a list of JTable methods and the JComponent ones won't be listed.

Hope there is a way. To search in a method-result-list won't help, I think.

Cheers!

Comment: I too wish for something like this. I had hoped there was a plug-in for something like this. Let me know if you figure out a way to do this.

Comment: I would like this feature too. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Am not sure how to exactly achieve this, but if you place your cursor on `JTable` and press

```
Ctrl+F3
```

You should able to see the list of methods that are present only on Jtable.

Comment: Ok, there I get the list I was looking for but I can't use it for code-completion. Is there an alternative for code-completion comparable to Ctrg+Space? Or another shortcut?